# PHP:mysql_query keeps returning false instead of number

Tags: php

The thing that I want to do:check if sessions are as it should be.
The code which checks it:

```
function evalLoggedUser($id,$e,$p)
{
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE id='$id' AND email='$e' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["email"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"]))
{
    $log_id       = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $log_email    = $_SESSION['email'];
    $log_password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($log_id,$log_email,$log_password);
}
```

And it returns this error:

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/diligenceh/domains/diligencehelps.com/public_html/php_includes/login_check.php on line 13 , which tells me that

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE id='$id' AND email='$e' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
```

returns false. It shouldn't return false since everything(as I think) is good with session variables.I set session variables in other file with the following syntax:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, email, password FROM members WHERE email='$e' AND password='$p' AND emailactivated='1' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$db_id = $row[0];
$db_email = $row[1];
$db_pass_str = $row[2];
$_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
$_SESSION['email'] = $db_email;
$_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
```

I'm getting $e and $p from ajax,when user sends data with submit button on login form. Maybe I've missed something writing this question, I'm pretty exausted so ask if any more info is needed.

Comment: You have to use `mysql_error()` to read the error message. You're also using an obsolete extension and your code is open to SQL injection.

Comment: Alvaro,I know that it's easily to get injected,I'm just using this code to be as easy for you to read as possible.

Comment: @Donny: If you know that your code is SQL-injectable, you should probably *fix it*.  Also, it looks suspiciously like you might be storing user passwords in plain text, which is grossly irresponsible.  You *might not be* (if you're hashing the user input elsewhere in code not shown), but it looks suspiciously like you are.

Comment: What type are the columns `id` and `activated`? Are they really textual fields?

Comment: @David Believe me,the code is really safe and passwords have hash,not just plain text.
Havelock - No, both of them are numeric, I've tried removing quotes but it didn't helped.

Comment: @Donny: If the *actual* code is not SQL-injectable but the *shown* code is, then how do you expect us to help without seeing the *actual* code?  In any event, if the query is returning `false` then clearly there's an error coming from the database.  You're not checking for errors.  It's usually a good idea to do that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: @David I am using EXACTLY the same code in question as I have, I just have removed all the unneeded code from my main code just so I could read it easier and fix it after fixing the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the PHP manual for [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) - a valid resource will be returned on success otherwise `false` will be returned.

Make sure you check the result from `mysql_query()` before you use mysql_num_rows:

```
if (($result = mysql_query($sql)) === false) {
   die('Problem with the query: '.mysql_error());
}
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Note: The way you are building `$sql` is ripe for SQL injection. And as others have pointed out, please use prepared statements or at least escape your values.

Comment: I've found the mistake by using your code, it said:
Problem with the query: Unknown column 'activated' in 'where clause'
The problem was that the column wasn't activated, it was emailactivated. Thanks for your help.